# Are chrome extensions safe?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to install a `chrome extension` is it always safe to use it?

Are there any risks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the safety of browser extensions. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Similar question on Security.SE: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38033/are-official-browser-add-ons-really-safe

Comment: @emilos Since you've posted the question on Stack Overflow, I assume that you've got some knowledge in reading and understanding source code. If so, install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin to review the source code of extensions prior installation.

Comment: I'm already doing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the extension.
You may want to have a look at this:
http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/01/malware-vendors-buy-chrome-extensions-to-send-adware-filled-updates

Answer (score 0):

well actually the are safe but they bring many unwanted things such my Search Bar, baybilon search etc... for example befault tab, addblock plus... and google is a very good company and you can trust it